# Displaying php results on a new page

Tags: php

I have seen examples and I have an idea of how to solve it, but the name on my checkbox I use uses concatenation. Because of this I do not know how to post the data on a new page using a name. I tried several ways and nothing so far. I need the data to posted on saveGames.php and I was then going to use a function to parse through the data and select the ones only with $id and checked (Example: "43checked")

UpcomingGames.php

```
<form name="saveGames" action="saveGames.php" method="post"> 

//Code

</form>


/*PHP function for setting up checkboxes for many different rows. I set up the name as $id which is the gameId and I added checkbox next to it so later I can parse through the data and select the ones with checked as the value because those games were selected. */

function checkbox($params)
{
  echo "<td>";
  $id = $params["gameID"];
  echo "<input id=\"$id\" type=\"checkbox\" name='". $id ."checkbox'>";
  echo "</td>";
}
```

Trying to post on this page saveGames.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>


<?php

  require_once('dbBaseDao.php');
  require_once('dbUserDao.php');
  require_once('dbBotDao.php');

  $userDao = new dbUserDao();
  $botDao = new dbBotDao();

 $ChosenGame = $_POST["'. $id 'checked"];

 echo $ChosenGame;

?>
```

Comment: because you are simply doing echo

Comment: echo means to writing on a whole page, it'll remove previous webpage contents

Comment: @AshishRatan I am not really familiar with PHP. So what exactly do I do to extract the data?

Comment: dont know if this is a typo for the example but a dot is missing on this line $ChosenGame = $_POST["'. $id 'checked"];  which should be $_POST[$id . 'checked']; or $_POST"$idchecked"];

Comment: it won't understand $id means, give a proper name and insert that value tag there u can change the value dynamically

like <input id=\"$id\" type=\"checkbox\" name="idName" value='". $id ."checkbox'>

Comment: try `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: then use to get the value like this:
**  $ChosenGame = $_POST["idName"];**

Comment: @ferozakbar This is the result I got on the page "Array ( [checkbox] => 38checkbox )" My question now is will the data that gets posted on to saveGames only be ones that have been selected? I thought posting will still extract all data to the new page and I will have to parse the data to find the game id and save it to the database?

Comment: @Sephedo I tried your variations and for some reason the data still doesn't display to the new page.

Comment: @AshishRatan I tried that variation as well and it still did not display anything.

Comment: @ferozakbar If I select multiple checkboxes it still only displays the last one that was selected not all of the checkboxes.

Comment: if u are using multiple checkbox then u can not get all values, u need to use array of che3ckbox values

Comment: I figured it out by doing a loop 
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo $check;
     } }

Comment: If you are wanting an array i believe the name of the form has to have [] on the end so name="checkbox[]"

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the word checkbox in the name part of the input tag. If no then the problem is solved.

If you want it then you have to find a method to pass the value stored in the variable $id to the next page.  You could use a hidden input tag for that.

Comment: I only wanted to use that to differentiate it. I thought when I extracted the post data that all the ones that were checked and not checked would go to the new page and then I would have to parse the data for the ones that were checked.

Comment: No, only the name of the checkbox get passed on to the next page as the key and the value mentioned in the respective input tag gets passed as  its value.

I have written a sample code to give you an idea as to how it works.



`<?php
 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  print_r($_POST);
 }
 
 
?>

<form method='post'>
 <input type='checkbox' name='car' value='benz'>Benz
 <input type='checkbox' name='car' value='audi'>Audi 
 <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>`